# Apply multidimension array data to an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion

For a given PHP object (loaded from CouchDB) `$obj`:

```
class stdClass#1 (3) {
    public $_id =>
    string(10) "nochecksum"
    public $_rev =>
    string(34) "1-4f734a24465bf7ba2de316fe87ffa0c1"
    public $rooms =>
    class stdClass#2 (1) {
        public $kitchen =>
        class stdClass#3 (1) {
            public $ceilingFan =>
            bool(false)
        }
    }
}
```

And for a given multidimensional array of data `$arr`, consisting of changed or new values for properties:

```
array(1) {
    'rooms' =>
    array(1) {
        'kitchen' =>
        array(1) {
            'needsCleaning' =>
            bool(true)
        }
    }
}
```

How is it possible to set `$obj`'s properties to be values from `$arr`?

The solution is simple for a single dimension array:

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $obj->{$k}=$v;
}
```

I tried with a recursive function, but I don't know how to reference the parent(s):

```
$obj = setObjectFromArray($obj, $arr);

function setObjectFromArray($obj, $arr, $tree=Array())
{
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $tree[]=$k;
            $obj = setObjectFromArray($obj, $v, $tree);
        } else {
            // Here $tree is Array('rooms','kitchen')
            // I want to set $obj->rooms->kitchen->{$k}
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

I think passing a reference of the object's property to the recursive function might work - but I don't understand either enough to make an educated guess. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function setObjectFromArray($obj, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $obj->{$k} = is_array($v) ? setObjectFromArray($obj->{$k}, $v) : $v;
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

The major difference with your code is the assignment to `$obj->{$k}` instead of `$obj`: that way you rewrite (or create) the property at each level of the recursion tree.

Be aware that even if you call the function like this:

```
$result = setObjectFromArray($obj, $arr);
```

... `$obj` will still have been modified and be equal to `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not totally obvious and maybe can fail somewhere but still - it's pair of `json` functions:

```
$r = array(
    'rooms' => array(
        'kitchen' => array(
            'needsCleaning' => true
        )
    )
);

echo '<pre>',print_r(json_decode(json_encode($r))), '</pre>';
```

**Explanation**: you encode array to json-string and then decode this string to object.

Maybe you can expand this code further.